# limitToLast is being ignored

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need some help please. I'm trying to retrieve the last 2 values from the firebase database, but the following code returns all 3 values. What am I doing wrong?

```
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("data/" + userId + "/contents/");
mDatabaseReference.limitToLast(2);

mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MyObject, MyObjectViewHolder>(
                MyObject.class,
                R.layout.item,
                MyViewHolder.class,
                mDatabaseReference) {...}
```

This is how my database structure looks like:

```
d5TPjSY2rJRrFJUF7nPrQWcGAjh1
 contents
 -KqKbcnMfHwYKChXHiCA
 -KqKbibX3f96ceVfoTLV
 -KrBrtsHeLaWv_gEUjIT
```

where d5TPjSY2rJRrFJUF7nPrQWcGAjh1 is the userId.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `limitToLast()` (or any other of the query methods), it returns a new object. You must use this new object.

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("data/" + userId + "/contents/");
Query query = mDatabaseReference.limitToLast(2);
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MyObject, MyObjectViewHolder>(
                MyObject.class,
                R.layout.item,
                MyViewHolder.class,
                query) {...}
```

Comment: thank you Frank! I missed that. By the way, I like your videos! :)